# Rendering a module's template contents in the page body

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I've been digging through the Drupal docs and haven't found a solution for this:

What I'm trying to do is to create a module with a URL using menu hooks. I've got that far. When this URL is viewed, I'd like to insert some HTML and JS code in the body but I haven't managed that. I've been trying to use templates.

This is what my module looks like:

```
<?php
  function hello_menu(){
    $items = array();

    $items['nodes'] = array(
      'title'            => t('My Nodes'),
      'page callback'    => 'helloworld_output',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

    return $items;
  }

  function hello_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
      'timeline' => array(
        'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
        'file' => 'timeline.tpl.php',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'hello')
      )
    );
  }

  function helloworld_output() {    
    header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline');    
    return theme('timeline', array());    
  }
?>
```

..and this is what I want rendered in the body.

```
<script>
    var tl;
    function onLoad() {
        alert('I have loaded');
    }
</script>
<div id="tl" class="timdef" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

If I place this code into my `timeline.tpl.php`, it doesn't get rendered in the page but before the whole content. Do I need to wrap this in PHP tags?

How can I get the `onLoad()` function to fire once my Drupal page is loaded. I a normal HTML page, I could use the `body onload=` callback.

(It looks really simple when you've worked with Drupal but for a first-timer, it's been a nightmare.)

Comment: Is the div getting added in your page ?

Comment: i Think you don't have to send the headers, It is set by Drupal core

Comment: @DineshKumar, Everything gets added to the page but before the HTML tag. It's right before Drupal spews out all the other content.

Comment: @DineshKumar, I removed those headers but the problem still exists. The `div` and `script` tags get printed at the beginning of the page before the `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add the JavaScript in Drupal is to have an external JS file like helloworld.js in your module/theme and include it using the function,

```
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });',
    array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5)
   );
  drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'external');
  drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('key' => 'value')), 'setting');
```

For more info see [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

> How can I get the onLoad() function to fire once my Drupal page is loaded. I a normal HTML page, I could use the body onload= callback

[jQuery(document).ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) is similar to your onload function that you are trying to call in your HTML body.

**UPDATE:**

Add the "template" instead of file in your  [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) for using templates like,

```
 function hello_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
    return array(
      'timeline' => array(
        'variables' => array('content' => NULL),
        'template' => 'timeline',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'hello')
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: @DinestKumar, would you know how I can output HTML from the template into my Drupal body? Do I need to `print` it from the template?

Comment: @MrFluff i have updated my answer

Comment: you have done it right, all you have to change the hook_theme. No need to print. You can use print to print the PHP variable